# Broken installer cannot uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-deployment

My VS2008 setup project has messed up, and now I can neither install, uninstall nor repair my application installation. I've tried various 'fixers', including the [MS one](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/) which after use reports all errors fixed, but with no improvement.

The application does not appear in Add Or Remove Programs, and I can't find any references to the application name in the registry either!

Nevertheless, when I try to do an install, the installer reports "Unable to continue because a version of  is already installed...."
If I try repair (rt-click the msi file) I get "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed" and if I try to uninstall I get "Preparing to remove" followed by "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed". So I can't go back and I can't go forwards.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this? Is there anything I can set in the registry that will fool the installer into thinking that it is not yet installed, so I can reinstall it, (or the reverse)?

I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Umm... it's not Visual Studio I want in unstall - it's the application I have written (with its installer and setup project) that I need to install.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding :).

Comment: Result so far: setup /le error.log:

error.log contains

=== Logging started: 21/01/2014  10:52:58 ===
Unable to continue because a version of Matrix5 is already installed. Use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall it before continuing.
=== Logging stopped: 21/01/2014  10:53:02 ===


setup /uninstall "Installer - Windows.msi" /le error.log

Message box: "This patch package could not be opened. Verify it exists.....etc"

Nothing in the log file.

Comment: Try looking up the ProductID and/or the UpgradeID GUID in the registry, these normally are the ones that indicate a package is installed or not.

Comment: Is that the ProductID found in the installer project Properties Window?

Comment: Yes you can find it there.

Comment: Ok - not found in the registry!

Comment: Checked the UpgradeID as well? Search without the dashes and the `{}` I expect you'd find them under here `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer` in the `UpgradeCodes` or `UserData\{{UserSID}}\Components` or `UserData\{{UserSID}}\Products`

Comment: Where do I find the upgradeID to search for?

Comment: Also in the project properties under "UpgradeCode".

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see that.

Comment: There's a similar location for your userprofile `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer`

Comment: Upgrade code not in my registry. Whee next? I'm all at sea here.

Comment: So the product code and upgrade code are not in the registry at all, I can't install and I can't uninstall and I can't repair. Is there no way out, short of resigning and walking away from it? There must be some way of faking the installation to the satisfaction of the uninstaller!

Comment: Can you suggest another forum perhaps where I might find an answer?

Comment: I suspect here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/home?forum=winformssetup

Comment: I think the question is really: what is found in the registry to prompt the installer to say "Unable to continue because a version of Matrix5 is already installed...." If I could put that back...